# How to have a tool tip on hover?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Is there any way I can have a tool tip or a pop over when I hover over the table column names. I basically want to have pop over which describes column names in R SHINY DATA TABLE.

Following is my code which renders a table. I have tried to search a lot on all forums and could not find a working code.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(

    DT::dataTableOutput("table2")

  ),

  server = function(input, output) {


output$table2<-DT::renderDataTable({
  responseDataFilter2_home<-iris[,c(4,3,1)]
  displayableData<-DT::datatable(responseDataFilter2_home,options = list(rowCallback = JS(
    "function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {",
    "var full_text = aData[1] + ','+ aData[2]",
    "$('td:eq(1)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);",
    "}")
  ))#, stringAsFactors = FALSe, row.names = NULL)
},server = TRUE, selection = 'single', escape=FALSE,options=list(paging=FALSE,searching = FALSE,ordering=FALSE,scrollY = 400,scrollCollapse=TRUE,
                                                                 columnDefs = list(list(width = '800%', targets = c(1)))),rownames=FALSE,colnames="Name")

  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

      mainPanel(
         dataTableOutput("irisTable")
      )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

   output$irisTable <- renderDataTable(
     iris[,c(4,3,1)], callback = JS("var tips = ['Row Names', 'Here goes one explanation', 'Here goes another explanation',
            'And here goes a final explanation'],
    header = table.columns().header();
for (var i = 0; i < tips.length; i++) {
  $(header[i]).attr('title', tips[i]);
}"))
   }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. However, when, I am running this R code and I can see no popups appear when I hover over the column headers of the data table IRIS. Could you please tell me where am I going wrong or send me a screenshot of what you see on your screen

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can add HTML to the column names over the parameter `colnames`

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(

    DT::dataTableOutput("table2")

  ),

  server = function(input, output) {


    output$table2<-DT::renderDataTable({
      responseDataFilter2_home<-iris[,c(4,3,1)]
      displayableData<-DT::datatable(
        responseDataFilter2_home,
        options = list(rowCallback = JS(
        "function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {",
        "var full_text = aData[1] + ','+ aData[2]",
        "$('td:eq(1)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);",
        "}"),
        paging=FALSE,
        searching = FALSE,
        ordering=FALSE,
        scrollY = 400,
        scrollCollapse=TRUE,
        columnDefs = list(
          list(width = '800%', targets = c(1)))),
        selection = 'single', 
        escape=FALSE,
        rownames=FALSE,
        colnames = c(HTML('<span title ="some popup">Here</span>'),HTML('<span title ="some other popup">Are</span>') , HTML('<span title ="yet another popup">Some</span>')))
    })
  }

)
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. However, when, I am running this R code and I can see no popups appear when I hover over the column headers of the data table. Could you please tell me where am I going wrong or send me a screenshot of what you see on your screen